# Strange behaviour of str in python

Tags: python, string

I have a problem with the following code:

```
str(0015)
```

Why does this return 13 and how can this be fixed?

Comment: in general: print 0015 will not print 0015 but 13 ... why ist this so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because number literals starting with a `0` are interpreted as octal numbers and octal `15` == decimal `13`:

```
>>>int('15',base=8)
13
```

or

```
>>>13 == 0015
True
```

If you need to get a string of 4 digits (`0015`) you may find handy the [`rjust`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rjust#str.rjust) function:

```
>>>str(15).rjust(4,'0')
'0015'
```

Comment: the OP may want to know how to get `'0015'` from `0015` ;)

Comment: @zhangxaochen Hmmm, probably is, I'll update the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because numbers starting with a `0` are treated as being in base 8 (octal). This is weird carry over from C that has since been regretted by the language's creator.

If you upgrade to Python 3.x, you'll find that the strange behaviour you report is gone and replaced with an error message. See [PEP 3127](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/).

Comment: +1 Didn't know that this feature is no longer used in Python3.